# ElasticSearch: Aggregating on field key

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to create a small dashboard in Kibana related to the most popular pages in my website. The documents are stored in the following format:

```
{
    "ev": "pageview",
    "meta": {
      "visitor": "blah",
      "pages": {
        "/my-route": {
          "title": "My route",
          "desc": "foo bar"
        },
        "/my-route#2": {
          "title": "My route 2"
          "desc": "foo bar"
        },
      }
    }
}
```

So, i'm trying to create a table that shows this:

```
Page     Views
/foo     10
/foo#2   10
/bar     5
```

However, i can't seem to be able to aggregate based on a key from an object. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think what you're asking is actually possible. How many routes do you have? Are they known in advance? If so, you can use a filter aggregation. It's not ideal (because you will have to manually write out all the routes), but it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your data structure is going to give you a difficult time for what you're trying to do.

I would propose you change it to this:

```
{
    "ev": "pageview",
    "visitor" :"blah",
    "route": "/my-route",
    "title":"My route",
    "desc" foo bar"
}
```

With a "keyword" mapping type for ev, visitor, and route, in addition to whatever other mappings you will need.

Then you could aggregate like this:

```
GET /{YOUR_INDEX}/_search
{
  "query": {"match_all": {}},
  "aggs": {
    "page_views": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "route",
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above aggregation would return the top 100 count page based on the counts of each cardinal "route" value.

Doing it with your current structure would require some pretty interesting scripts, if it's even possible at all.

Edit* I wanted to note that I'm assuming you want to aggregate across all documents following your structure. If you're only looking for counts within that single document based on its nested objects, there may be an approach.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change the data structure. Also, each view can contain multiple pages.

Comment: This suggestion seems right to me. It doesn't matter that each view can contain multiple pages -- they'll just map to multiple documents. If you can't change the data structure, can you maintain a separate index, updated periodically with the new docs?